# VB: Copy a Range to another Excel Application

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to solve a relatively simple problem but I can't realize it. My aim is to copy a range of cells in a worksheet of the main Excel Application to another range (of the same size) in a worksheet of a second newly created Excel Application. I create the second Application by using

```
Set secondExApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

I'm using this reference for further handling. Until now I've tried two different ways. Both don't work properly.

0.: Preparation / Introduction

```
Set srcWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set srcSheet = srcWb.Worksheets("example")

Set dstApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set dstWb = dstApp.Workbooks(1)
Set dstSheet = dstWb.Worksheets(1)
```

1.: PasteSpecial - delivers an **image(!)** instead of just the range

```
srcSheet.Range("A1:B2").Copy
dstSheet.Range("A1:B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

2.: Range.Copy [Destination] - does not work - Is it right that I can only use this method for sheets in the same application?

```
srcSheet.Range(srcSheet.Cells(..., ...), srcSheet.Cells(..., ...)).Copy _
dstSheet.Range(dstSheet.Cells(..., ...), dstSheet.Cells(..., ...))
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

*Edit*:
I've already played with the "record macro" functionality but I prefer coding it on my own without "selecting" or "activating" cells / sheets / etc.

---

*Edit (**solved**)*:
Thank you both GSerg and iDevlop very much, you delivered a good further starting point for me. I did some research as far as the Excel constants as `xlClipboardFormatDspText` are concerned.

What really helped me was the fact that opening a new Excel instance changes the Paste(Special) menu.

So instead of creating a new instance I now simply add a workbook (which can be hidden) and use this object to add my content. Since it is held in the same instance (also have a look at the task manager) the Paste(Special) menu is completely the same.

Now it is possible to use Range.Copy [destination] even without select!

**Result**:

```
'Hides the new workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set dstWb = Workbooks.Add
Set dstSheet = dstWb.Worksheets(1)

srcSheet.Range(srcSheet.Cells(..., ...), srcSheet.Cells(..., ...)).Copy
dstSheet.Paste dstSheet.Range(dstSheet.Cells(..., ...), dstSheet.Cells(..., ...))

'Avoids the often seen dashed border around the copied range
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Setting the initial change back
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

---

Software: Excel 2007

Comment: Why using a second Excel app instead of another workbook in the same instance of Excel ? The only bonus I can see is to take advantage of dual core processor for huge calculations. But it is slower if you don't need that.

Comment: @iDevlop How funny. I just read your comment after I found out on myself. Very useful comment!

Answer (score 4):

As determined by poking Excel with a stick, you have to use `Worksheet.Paste` for inter-excel stuff:

```
srcSheet.Range("A1:B2").Copy
dstSheet.Paste dstSheet.Range("A1")
```

---

Poking Excel with a thicker stick revealed that formulas get preserved when pasting from Clipboard as `xlClipboardFormatDspText`:

```
srcSheet.Range("A1:B2").Copy
dstSheet.Range("A1").Select
dstSheet.PasteSpecial xlClipboardFormatDspText, False
```

However, this does require selecting a cell on dstSheet first, because `Worksheet.PasteSpecial` uses active cell.

Comment: Thank you GSerg! This works fine except for the fact that **formulas** aren't transmitted. Is there a way to include formulas? And why does the PasteSpecial method not work?

Comment: @Mic It does work, but uses not the format you want. See my edit.

Comment: This does not work for me either. The result is some kind of a single column table with a CSV list in each cell containing a row. But please see my comment!

Comment: @Mic Oh well. Seems like there are many more locale-dependent nice little surprises in Excel. The result you desribe I get when trying `xlClipboardFormatCSV`.