# vlookup and return entire cell including formatting from non active workbook

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm looking to `vlookup` a value from a `tableArray` on a different workbook and return the value and entire cells content.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22154078/2071807) is nearly what I'm looking for.

If I amend this links `copyFormatting` routine (`Private Sub copyFormatting(destCell As Range, srcCell As Range)`) to copy the cell and paste all instead of formatting the cells font:

```
srcCell.Copy
destCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Then the code works as is when the return value is within the same workbook.

Any ideas how I can get the set range line -

```
fromCell.Parent.Range(destAddr)
```

to work when referencing a cell address in another workbooks sheet?

Comment: Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Comment: Thanks. The pasting code works fine. It's the set range on another workbook that isn't working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8560340/11683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set extractDestRange = Range(destAddr) 'fromCell.Parent

commenting out the fromCell.Parent reference fixes this.